# Since when do X-Men comics exist in X-Men?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, logan

In the second Logan trailer,  we see that X-Men comics exist in the X-Men universe:

> LOGAN:  [leafs through X-Men comic] We've got ourselves an X-Men fan ... Maybe a quarter of it happened ... but not like this.

Is this the first such instance in an X-Men property (excluding the specifically fourth wall-breaking cases like Deadpool)?

Comment: Note that those comics were made specifically for the movie, as Fox doesn't own the rights to use X-Men comics.

Comment: In the Marvel comics universe, comics exist for most of the major "real" heroes and groups.  They even once did a special line of one-shots, each supposedly being an example of a comic of that exists within the Marvel universe focusing on the characters.  Many of the characters were reasonably close because they licensed the rights to their name/image, but for characters like Spidey and the X-Men they went wildly off-book.

Comment: @starpilotsix, that may be the makings of a great answer if you back it up more

Comment: Is Logan part of the X-men cinematic universe? I think I remember Hugh Jackman saying this movie is a stand-alone...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, within the Marvel comics universe, comic books exist for many of the major characters.  Some, like the Fantastic Four, "authorize" Marvel (the company) to do stories loosely based on their adventures (and the in-universe Captain America comics were, for a time, actually **drawn** by Steve Rogers), but for characters like the X-Men and Spidey, who are less in the public eye, it's largely made up.

[Here's an article at CBR](http://www.cbr.com/what-comic-books-look-like-in-the-marvel-universe/) which gives a brief but entertaining rundown of the phenomenon.

The article does mention the X-Men in particular, with respect to a particular stunt Marvel (the real world company) did in 2000 under the banner "Marvel Comics Group", in which the real company published the comics that their in-universe counterparts published for several groups.  One of these was X-Men.

[image]

Described as follows:

> “X-Men” #1 by Mark Millar, Sean Phillips and Duncan Fegredo was a compelling look at the power of prejudice, as the Marvel Universe was so biased against mutants in general that this book, about a team of mutants captured by Sentinels and forced to work on a suicide mission for Colonel America, is a striking example of what those biases would look like as it crept into the popular culture of the time…